# Blazor app, how to add model state validation error?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

How do I add a custom validation message in the SaveItem event (prefer not to use data annotations)? It should show up in the "ValidationMessage For=" context.

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@page "/edititem"


<EditForm Model="@model" OnSubmit="@Submit" OnValidSubmit="@SaveItem">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="ItemName" @bind-Value="@model.ItemName" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.ItemName)" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    ItemModel model = new ItemModel();

    private void Submit()
    {

    }
    private void SaveItem()
    {


    }

    public class ItemModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string ItemName{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, you could create your own custom component but for most uses that would surely be overkill. What's your objection to using data annotations? [Required(ErrorMessage ="xxx Is Required")]

Comment: For this validation, I have to check the database and would prefer to do it in the component event rather than data annotation.

Answer (score 5):

```cs
<EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnSubmit="@Submit" 
     OnValidSubmit="@SaveItem">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText id="ItemName" @bind-Value="@model.ItemName" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.ItemName)" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext? editContext;
    private ValidationMessageStore? messageStore;
    ItemModel model = new ItemModel();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(model);

        messageStore = new(editContext);
    }

    private void Submit()
    {

    }
    private void SaveItem()
    {
        messageStore.Add(() => model.ItemName, "ItemName invalid");
    }

    public class ItemModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string ItemName{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

To achieve custom validation outside data-attributes follow those 3 steps:

1. Declare an EditContext and a ValidationMessageStore objects in your page;
2. Bind your form to the EditContext instance (in your case you have to remove the Model attribute);
3. Perform custom validation and display the error adding an item to the messageStore object;

Comment: You can find additional information about validation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom validation in server side by add some Component which contain error message.
[Display validation error from the server](https://remibou.github.io/Using-the-Blazor-form-validation/)

Comment: Please consider adding the relevant information rather than a link.